# What IP address range do URLFetch queries come from?

Tags: google

I want to set my firewall to only allow HTTP connections that originate from [Apps Script](http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/).  My Google Spreadsheets project uses URLFetch make queries back to my server.  For development, that "server" is just my desktop at home.  To allow that, I had to set a rule in the firewall to allow TCP on port 80.  Restricting source address is never a substitute for real security, but it would block most of the scripts that periodically scan my IP for IIS/Apache vulnerabilities.  So far, the legitimate connections are coming from 66.249.85.66.  Presumably, that could change at any time.  I can't get reverse DNS on that (i.e., "host 66.249.85.66") so I can't even do much weaker programmatic filtering.

Is there a known IP address range that Apps Script sends URLFetch connects from?

Alternate suggestions are also welcome.  Unfortunately, App Engine won't work.  It's not compatible with my application.

Answer (score 4):

```
216.239.32.0 - 216.239.63.255
64.233.160.0 - 64.233.191.255
66.249.80.0 - 66.249.95.255
72.14.192.0 - 72.14.255.255
209.85.128.0 - 209.85.255.255
66.102.0.0 - 66.102.15.255
74.125.0.0 - 74.125.255.255
64.18.0.0 - 64.18.15.255
207.126.144.0 - 207.126.159.255
173.194.0.0 - 173.194.255.255
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/jdbc#accessing

Answer (score 3):

The second line in the top part of the documentation for UrlFetchApp tells you how to get the IP addresses to whitelist.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app

> Requests made using this service originate from a set pool of IP ranges. You can [look up the full list of IP addresses](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/#static-ip) if you need to whitelist or approve these requests.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my list. Most are from ionFish's list but some I've gleaned from web server log files. It's probably still incomplete though.

```
107.178.192.138
107.178.192.142
107.178.192.146
107.178.192.85-107.178.192.87
107.178.224.10
107.178.224.12
107.178.224.14
173.194.0.0-173.194.255.255
207.126.144.0-207.126.159.255
209.85.128.0-209.85.255.255
216.239.32.0-216.239.63.255
64.18.0.0-64.18.15.255
64.233.160.0-64.233.191.255
66.102.0.0-66.102.15.255
66.249.80.0-66.249.95.255
72.14.192.0-72.14.255.255
74.125.0.0-74.125.255.255
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the two lists [0] from google to build a list. You don't want their public cloud IPs so it seems you'll need to subtract public cloud IPs from their total IP list.  I used the program net-consolidator to do the subtracting. I don't know how good the python program is. This is my first time using it.

[0] https://support.google.com/a/answer/10026322

Reference : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app

Commands:

```
curl -s https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog.txt > full
curl -s https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/cloud.json > subtract.json
jq '.prefixes[].ipv4Prefix' subtract.json > subtract.quote
cat subtract.quote  | sed 's/"//g'  |grep -v nul > subtract

git clone https://github.com/TKCERT/net-consolidator

python3 net-consolidator/net-consolidator.py -f full -s subtract
```

Which gave me this list. I didn't actually verify the accuracy of this generated list.

```
8.8.4.0/24
8.8.8.0/24
8.35.200.0/21
34.64.0.0/18
34.96.0.0/18
34.98.0.0/18
34.98.136.0/21
34.98.144.0/20
34.98.160.0/19
34.98.192.0/18
34.99.0.0/16
34.100.0.0/17
34.101.0.0/20
34.101.16.0/23
34.101.19.0/24
34.101.28.0/22
34.101.32.0/19
34.103.0.0/16
34.104.0.0/20
34.104.16.0/21
34.104.24.0/23
34.104.26.0/24
34.104.28.0/22
34.104.32.0/20
34.104.48.0/24
34.104.53.0/24
34.104.54.0/23
34.104.56.0/23
34.109.0.0/16
34.110.0.0/17
34.112.0.0/14
34.116.8.0/21
34.116.16.0/20
34.116.32.0/19
34.118.128.0/17
34.119.0.0/16
34.124.64.0/19
34.124.96.0/20
34.126.0.0/18
34.126.224.0/19
34.127.128.0/19
34.127.160.0/20
34.127.176.0/24
34.127.181.0/24
34.127.182.0/23
34.127.184.0/23
34.127.192.0/18
34.128.0.0/16
34.142.128.0/17
34.143.0.0/16
34.144.0.0/16
34.152.64.0/18
34.152.128.0/17
34.153.0.0/16
34.154.0.0/15
34.156.0.0/16
34.157.8.0/21
34.157.32.0/22
34.157.44.0/22
34.157.80.0/20
34.157.96.0/19
34.157.136.0/21
34.157.160.0/22
34.157.172.0/22
34.157.208.0/20
34.157.224.0/19
34.158.0.0/16
34.160.0.0/13
34.174.0.0/15
34.177.0.0/16
34.178.0.0/15
34.180.0.0/14
34.184.0.0/13
35.187.128.0/20
35.190.96.0/20
35.190.240.0/20
35.191.0.0/16
35.199.128.0/20
35.201.32.0/21
35.201.40.0/24
35.201.42.0/23
35.201.44.0/22
35.201.48.0/20
35.203.192.0/20
35.203.208.0/23
35.203.220.0/22
35.203.224.0/21
35.203.240.0/20
35.206.0.0/19
35.218.0.0/16
35.219.192.0/18
35.220.28.0/23
35.220.30.0/24
35.229.0.0/20
35.230.192.0/19
35.230.224.0/20
35.235.128.0/18
35.235.192.0/20
35.235.208.0/21
35.235.224.0/19
35.242.28.0/23
35.242.30.0/24
35.243.16.0/20
35.243.48.0/21
64.15.112.0/20
64.233.160.0/19
66.102.0.0/20
66.249.64.0/19
70.32.128.0/19
72.14.192.0/18
74.114.24.0/21
74.125.0.0/16
104.154.0.0/20
104.154.112.0/24
104.154.122.0/23
104.154.124.0/22
104.155.240.0/20
104.196.64.0/24
104.196.72.0/21
104.196.80.0/20
104.199.64.0/23
104.199.240.0/23
104.237.160.0/19
107.178.192.0/20
107.178.224.0/20
108.170.192.0/18
108.177.0.0/17
130.211.0.0/22
136.112.0.0/12
142.250.0.0/15
146.148.0.0/23
172.110.32.0/21
172.217.0.0/16
172.253.0.0/16
173.194.0.0/16
192.178.0.0/15
193.186.4.0/24
199.36.154.0/23
199.36.156.0/24
199.192.112.0/23
199.192.114.0/24
199.223.237.0/24
199.223.238.0/23
207.223.160.0/20
208.65.152.0/22
208.68.108.0/22
208.81.188.0/22
208.117.224.0/19
209.85.128.0/17
216.58.192.0/19
216.73.80.0/20
216.239.32.0/19
```